# Moto G4 Plus doesn't boot after root

Tags: rooting, twrp, unbricking, supersu

## I have a rooted Moto G4+ running Lineage OS...

Due to fast battery drain, I want to revert to the stock ROM, but I still want to have root. I managed to restore an old backup with no errors.

Now, when I tried rooting it by flashing SuperSu zip from TWRP, it just didn't boot afterwards. It didn't even show Motorola's annoying unlocked bootloader warning. (I could still get to bootloader mode and recovery)

I restored the backup again, then tried to root with other versions of SuperSu, but all resulted in the same black screen and wouldn't boot.

I then tried to root with Magisk by flashing Magisk zip file, but I ended up with the same issue.

I have a strong suspicion that the cause of this problem is the modification of the boot image because both of the zips modified the boot image, yet other zips such as a boot animation worked perfectly fine.

## So my question is:

How can I get my device rooted on stock ROM without losing my ability to boot?

Comment: What is the stock version you are restoring that is working properly, Marshmallow or Nougat?

Answer (score 0):

Go to recovery and do "Wipe" or "Factory Reset"

It should help the bootloop problem

Comment: King Root doesn't have a root method for my phone

Comment: Try SuperSu....

Comment: Note, I mentioned in my question that I already tried that...

Comment: I'll try the factory reset

Comment: Oh there are thousands of rooting application on the Internet try KingoRoot

Comment: I've tried a bunch of them, none seem to work...

Comment: I've also noticed if you Factory reset a device The root won't get deleted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67824/discussion-between-android-helper-and-abraham-murciano-benzadon).

Comment: Do not use any Kingroot/Kingoroot on a Moto device, it often leads to bricking. There is no need for these exploit based rooting tools on a Moto device, the methods of rooting are different, but clearly documented and working. Please update your original question with the version you are restoring, as specific as possible, that is functional.

Comment: @acejavelin I'd never thought about that...I am currently using Samsung Tab 4 Which king root works well

Comment: @Android_Helper King(o)root and other "one click root" methods are all exploit based, and in Lollipop and older Android versions it can work where more standard methods were not available. In Marshmallow and newer there are more security measures than older versions of Android and using these exploit based rooting methods can cause lots of issues, not to mention the known spyware/malware issues that can occur with many of these tools. This isn't really the forum to discuss it, but I always suggest looking in XDA Developers for known working methods prior to attempting any exploit method.